# Does anyone know how to parse a bytes value from local state returned by the client?

Tags: smartcontracts, algorand

I'm trying to parse bytes from local state returned by client.

Basically I want to convert it back to binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it with a base 64 decoder to convert back that object to binary file/bytes.

[Here's a link on how you can do it](https://github.com/algorand-devrel/beaker/blob/master/beaker/client/state_decode.py)

[image]

If you found it useful! make sure to **give this answer a Upvote :)**